# Is it possible in Python to decorate a function so that its begin and end are logged?

Tags: python, python-decorators

For logging, I would like each function to log its own name at the start and end of the function.

```
def my_function():
    print("Enter my_function")
    # ...
    print("Leave my_function")
```

If I change the name of the function, I have to update these print messages as well. I am looking for a way to automate this.

```
def my_decorator(func):
    print("Enter ", func.__name__)
    func()
    print("Leave ", func.__name__)

def my_function():
    # do the work
    pass

# main:
my_decorator(my_function)
```

Is this possible in a simple way, maybe using decorators? How would this look like if my_function had parameters?

Comment: What I don't understand is how you failed to find any of the tutorials on decorators which explain how to do exactly this. It's pretty much the canonical example for decorators.

Comment: You may want to read on context managers in Python (with statements): that's what they're there for. https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are right, using a decorator is a perfect way to implement such behavior.

What you need to know is how a decorator works: it simply takes a function as an argument, and returns another function. This other returned function is intended to wrap your argument function.

```
def log_in_out(func):

    def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Enter ", func.__name__)
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Leave ", func.__name__)
        return result

    return decorated_func

@log_in_out
def my_function():
    print("Inside my_function")
    return 42


val = my_function()

print(val)

# Output:
# Enter  my_function
# Inside my_function
# Leave  my_function
# 42
```

Also, note that the answer of @ŁukaszRogalski using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is usefull for preserving the function docstring.

Finally, a good idea from @MartinBonner, is that you can also use it to log the errors in your function:

```
def log_in_out(func):

    def decorated_func(*args, **kwargs):
        name = func.__name__
        print("Enter", name)
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Leave", name)
        except:
            print("Error in", name)
            raise
        return result

    return decorated_func
```

Note that I re-throw the error because I think the control flow should be managed from the outside of the function.

For more advanced logging, you should use [the built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) which provides many facilities.

Comment: For the icing on the cake, you could add support for the case where the wrapped function throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's really simple with star args and star kwargs. `functools.wraps` is used to rewrite any metadata (`__name__`, `__doc__` etc.) from input function to wrapper. If function object string representation is too verbose to you, you may use `print("Enter", f.__name__)` instead.

```
import functools


def d(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Enter", f)
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Exit", f)
        return result
    return wrapper


@d
def my_func():
    print("hello")


@d
def my_func2(x):
    print(x)


my_func()
my_func2("world")
```

Output:

```
Enter <function my_func at 0x10ca93158>
hello
Exit <function my_func at 0x10ca93158>
Enter <function my_func2 at 0x10caed950>
world
Exit <function my_func2 at 0x10caed950>
```